# ploting subplot in matplotlib with pandas issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

i am try to plot subplot in matplotlib with pandas but there are issue i am facing. when i am plot subplot not show the date of stock...there is my program

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas.io.data

df = pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo('goog', start=datetime.datetime(2008,1,1),end=datetime.datetime(2014,10,23))
fig = plt.figure()
r = fig.patch
r.set_facecolor('#0070BB')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1, axisbg='#0070BB')
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.plot(df['Close'])

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2, axisbg='#0070BB')
ax2.plot(df['Volume'])
plt.show()
```

run this program own your self and solve date issue.....

Comment: This Code is work perfectly, and gives this result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lF6KI.png. Check your packages, or share the error message.

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling [matplotlib's plot()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot), you are only giving it one array (e.g. df['Close'] in the first case). When there's only one array, matplotlib doesn't know what to use for the x axis data, so it just uses the index of the array. This is why your x axis shows the numbers 0 to 160: there are presumably 160 items in your array.

Use `ax1.plot(df.index, df['Close'])` instead, since df.index should hold the date values in your pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas.io.data

df = pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo('goog', start=datetime.datetime(2008,1,1),end=datetime.datetime(2014,10,23))
fig = plt.figure()
r = fig.patch
r.set_facecolor('#0070BB')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1, axisbg='#0070BB')
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.plot(df.index, df['Close'])

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2, axisbg='#0070BB')
ax2.plot(df.index, df['Volume'])
plt.show()
```